# Move the virtualenvs to another host folder

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

By error, I forgot to specify the `WORKON_HOME` variable before creating my virtual environments, and they were created in `/root/.virtualenvs` directory. They worked fine, and I did some testing by activating certain environment and then doing `(env)$ pip freeze` to see what specific modules are installed there.

So, whe I discovered the workon home path error, I needed to change the host directory to `/usr/local/pythonenv`. I created it and moved all the contents of `/root/.virtualenvs` directory to `/usr/local/pythonenv`, and changed the value of `WORKON_HOME` variable. Now, activating an environment using workon command seems to work fine (ie, the promt changes to `(env)$`), however if I do `(env)$ pip freeze`, I get way longer list of modules than before and those do not include the ones installed in that particular env before the move.

I guess that just moving the files and specifying another dir for `WORKON_HOME` variable was not enough. Is there some config where I should specify the new location of the host directory, or some config files for the particular environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Virtualenvs are not by default relocatable. You can use `virtualenv --relocatable <virtualenv>` to turn an existing virtualenv into a relocatable one, and see if that works. But that option is [experimental](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html#making-environments-relocatable) and not really recommended for use.

The most reliable way is to create new virtualenvs. Use `pip freeze -l > requirements.txt` in the old ones to get a list of installed packages, create the new virtualenv, and use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the packages in the new one.

Comment: Ok, I was just worried that if I try to set up new virtualenv, something could go wrong because of the WORKON_HOME change. After all, there are bunch of executable files in it. But now I just deleted the failed virtualenv's folder, created with `mkvirtualenv env` anew, and reinstalled the packages. Success! I still don't know what for are those files in the WORKON-HOME, but for now I have functional virtualenvs and I am happy.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `virtualenv --relocatable` feature. It seemed to work but then I found a different python version installed:

```
$ . VirtualEnvs/moslog/bin/activate
(moslog)$ ~/VirtualEnvs/moslog/bin/mosloganalisys.py 
python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Remember to recreate the same virtualenv tree on the destination host.